# Python, modifying a blackjack game

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am in need of help with an assignment I have been given.

I have been asked to modify the section below from a blackjack game so that a dealer deals a card to each player and the highest card wins unless there is a draw.

I am unable to get the code right for this.

#### This is what i have in place:

```
for player in self.still_playing:
            if player.total > self.players.total:
                player.win()
            elif player.total < self.players.total:
                player.lose()
            else:
                player.push()
```

#### here is the rest of the code:

```
import Cards, Games

class BJ_Card(Cards.Card):
# Defines a Blackjack card
    ACE_VALUE = 1
    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.is_face_up:
            val = BJ_Card.CARDS.index(self.card) + 1
            if val > 10:
                val = 10
        else:
            val = None
        return val
    # This object returns a number between 1 and 10,
    # representing the value of a Blackjack card

class BJ_Deck(Cards.Deck):
# Defines a Blackjack deck
    def populate(self):
        for suit in BJ_Card.SUITS:
            for card in BJ_Card.CARDS:
                self.cards.append(BJ_Card(card, suit))

class BJ_Hand(Cards.Hand):
# Defines a Blackjack hand
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(BJ_Hand, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + ":\t" + super(BJ_Hand, self).__str__()
        if self.total:
            rep += "(" + str(self.total) + ")"
        return rep
    @property
    def total(self):
    # If a card has the value None, then total is None
        for card in self.cards:
            if not card.value:
                return None
        # Add card values
        t = 0
        for card in self.cards:
            t += card.value
        # Check if hand contains an Ace
        contains_ace = False
        for card in self.cards:
            if card.value == BJ_Card.ACE_VALUE:
                contains_ace = True
        # treat Ace as 1
        contains_ace = 1
        
        return t
    def is_busted(self):
         return self.total > 21

class BJ_Player(BJ_Hand):
# Defines a Blackjack player
     def is_hitting(self):
        response = Games.askYesNo("\n" + self.name + ", do you want another 
card? (Y/N): ")
        return response == "y"
    def bust(self):
        print(self.name, "busts.")
        self.lose()
    def lose(self):
        print(self.name, "loses.")
    def win(self):
        print(self.name, "wins.")
    def push(self):
        print(self.name, "draws.")
    
class BJ_Dealer(BJ_Hand):
# Defines a Blackjack dealer
    def is_hitting(self):
        return self.total < 17
    def bust(self):
        print(self.name, "busts.")
    def flip_first_card(self):
        first_card = self.cards[0]
        first_card.flip()
    
class BJ_Game(object):
# Defines a Blackjack game
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.players = []
        for name in names:
            player = BJ_Player(name)
            self.players.append(player)
        self.dealer = BJ_Dealer("Dealer")
        self.deck = BJ_Deck()
        self.deck.populate()
        self.deck.shuffle()
    @property
    def still_playing(self):
         sp = []
        for player in self.players:
            if not player.is_busted():
                sp.append(player)
        return sp
    def __additional_cards(self, player):
        while not player.is_busted() and player.is_hitting():
            self.deck.deal([player])
            print(player)
            if player.is_busted():
                player.bust()
    def play(self):
        # Deal initial 1 card to all players
        self.deck.deal(self.players, per_hand = 1)
        for player in self.players:
            print(player)
        
        
        for player in self.still_playing:
            if player.total > self.players.total:
                player.win()
            elif player.total < self.players.total:
                player.lose()
            else:
                player.push()
        
    

    # Remove everyone's cards
        for player in self.players:
            player.clear()              
        

def main():
    print("\nWelcome to the Python Blackjack game.\n")
    names = []
    number = Games.askForNumber("How many players? (2-7): ", low = 2, high = 
8)
    print()
    i = 1
    for i in range(number):
        name = input("Enter player name: ")
        if name == "":
            names.append("Anon")
            print()
            i += 1
        else:
            names.append(name)
            print()
            i += 1
    game = BJ_Game(names)
    again = "Y"
    while again == "y" or again == "Y":
        game.play()
        again = Games.askYesNo("\nDo you want to play again?: ")
main()
```

Comment: Please explain the actual problem you're having with your code. What section have you verified works? What currently happens vs what you expect to happen?

Comment: I am at the end of modifying this blackjack game for my assignment the game is to be highest card wins, the section i am stuck with modifying is :                            
    for player in self.still_playing:
                if player.total > self.players.total:
                    player.win()
                elif player.total < self.players.total:
                    player.lose()
                else:
                    player.push()

Comment: I am unable to get my brain around how I can measure the players cards against each players card that has been dealt. when i run the code I get:            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\HighestCard\HighestCard.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\HighestCard\HighestCard.py", line 148, in main
    game.play()
  File "C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\HighestCard\HighestCard.py", line 115, in play
    if player.total > self.players.total:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'total'

Comment: Please add all relevant information in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.players
```

is a list of BJ_Player classes / objects. You're calling self.players.total i.e trying to get the property total of a python list which does not exist as this is not a property of a list. I assume you're trying to do something more like;

```
for player in self.players:
    print(player.total)
```

this way you would be accessing each players total. However, the class BJ_Player does not appear to have a total property either, so you will need to add this to the class and then use a loop like the one given above.